# embedded http server : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: asp.net, response, mp4, httpserver

I'm using a Customizable-Embedded-HTTPServer for a project.
Simply I'm calling response.SendFile(@"E:\folder\xx.mp4", "video/mp4")
to play video files located at local folder.
But it gives me "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error. I've searched a lot but couldn't find a solution!

```
 public void SendFile(string path, string mediaType)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Assert(_stream == null);

            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                this.Date = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
                this.ContentLength = fs.Length;
                this.ContentType = mediaType;
                this.ChunkedTransferEncoding = false;
                _stream = new HTTPOutputStream(_session);
                Write(_stream);
                int rc;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[65536];
                do
                {
                    isPlaying = true;
                    rc = fs.Read(bytes, 0, 65536);
                    _stream.Write(bytes, 0, rc);

                } while (rc != 0);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex);
        }
    }
```

When I debug I noticed that it is entering SendFile method more than once somehow, this can be the issue, but I don't know why that happens. Another question with this method I can't jump to forward in the video, how can I do that?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: proxy settings given in web.config?

Comment: it is a win embedded http server project.

Comment: When I debug I noticed that it is entering SendFile method more than once somehow, this can be the issue, but I don't know why that happens. Another question with this method I can't jump to forward in the video, how can I do that?

Comment: please edit/update the question with issues

Comment: ok, i updated the question, any idea?